# Angular 4 - Format SQL Time

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I format a time type value returned from SQL?
For example, `{{value.SundayStart}}` returns 10:00:00.

I want to display it without the seconds,
but using Angular's date pipe:

`{{value.SundayStart | date: 'hh:mm'}}`

is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use the date pipe with only a time value. Simply use the slice pipe instead:

```
{{value.SundayStart | slice:0:5}}
```

This returns `10:00`

Answer (score 1):

Quite a dirty solution, though it works. Little bit of work around. Create a date-time object using the `time` returned by `sql` and then format to display time in `HH:mm`.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  time =  '23:34:12';
  dateTime = new Date();

 constructor() {
   let times = this.time.split(':');
   this.dateTime.setHours(parseInt(times[0]));
   this.dateTime.setMinutes(parseInt(times[1]));
   this.dateTime.setSeconds(parseInt(times[2]));
 }
}
```

.html

```
{{dateTime | date : 'HH:mm'}}
```